# What kind of algorithm do i need when the place of numbers changing according to n number?

Tags: matrices

I have a project in Golang. But i don't have any idea about how to solve it.

n will be an odd number (Feedback will be given if an odd number is not written)

- As output, a structure with n*n matrix appearance will be created according to the following rules and printed on the screen.

### Rules

The rules will be transferred assuming the entered number is 3. (Any number can be entered)

- The first number will be in the middle column of the first row.
- The next number is placed in the diagonal square, to the top right.
- In such a case, the overflowing number is placed at the bottom of the column in the section it is in.
- The next number is placed in the diagonal square, to the top right.
- If the number overflows from the right, it is placed on the leftmost row.
- The next number is placed in the diagonal square, to the top right.
- If the cell is full, it is placed under the previously placed number. The number 4 is placed under the number 3.
- The next number, the number 5, is placed in the diagonal square to the top right.
- The next number, the number 6, is placed in the diagonal square to the top right.
- The next number, 7, is placed in the diagonal square to the top right.
- In case of cross overflow, it is placed below the previous number.
- For other numbers, the above rules are applied.
- Since the number 8 overflows from the right, it is placed on the far left in the line it is in.
- The number 9 overflows.
- In case of overflow, it is placed at the bottom of the column.
- All numbers are placed by operating the rules.

here's the output for `n = 3`

```
Enter the number : 3
8 1 6 
3 5 7 
4 9 2
```

[image: output for n=3]

[image: output]

I can make the zigzag matrix but I can't build an algorithm for this question. Can anyone help me about building the algorithm?

Progress:

I noticed that the sums of each row and column are equal. For example:

- `n=3` ==> the sum of each row and column of the resulting matrix is equal to each other and to 15.
- `n=5` ==> the sum of each row and column of the resulting matrix is equal to each other and 65.
- `n=7` ==> the sum of each row and column of the resulting matrix is equal to each other and 175.
- `n=9` ==> the sum of each row and column of the resulting matrix is equal to each other and 369.

Comment: The first four *rules* pretty much spell it out: What more of a *specification of well-defined steps to populate an n × n square* do you need? Does Golang pose obstacles?

Answer (score 0):

Your observations to the sum of rows and columns hold the hint. Its a magic square !

There are numerous articles that go in depth into the construction of these squares and how they hold the properties they have. One of them [here](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/making-magic-squares/).

Now, the algorithm is just understanding these properties and then scaling them out to bigger N. The article I linked above shows a way to create a 9x9 square by treating it as a set of 9 3x3 squares.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func array(n int) (int, []int) {

    m := make([]int, n*n)
    A := func(x int) int { return (x + n - 1) % n }
    i, j := n/2, 0
    for k := 1; k <= n*n; k++ {
        m[i*n+j] = k
        if m[A(i)*n+A(j)] != 0 {
            j = (j + 1) % n
        } else {
            i, j = A(i), A(j)
        }
    }
    return n, m
}

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Print("Enter the n number: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)

    if n%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Please enter a valid number")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("n number: ", n)
        n, m := array(n)
        j := 2
        for i := 1; i <= n*n; i *= 10 {
            j++
        }
        f := fmt.Sprintf("%%%dd", j)
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                fmt.Printf(f, m[i*n+j])
            }
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }

}
```

here's the golang code for building n*n matrix (n is a number from user)which is a magic square